# Latin based Japanse input

Tags: c++, localization

I'm working on Japanese input system for device with 10-digit numeric keypad.
That's why I'm searching for some not complicated input method that can be implemented on c++.

I've implemented Pinyin method for Chinese input. Each Chinese symbol can be reached by some Latin symbol combination and then chosen from the list. For example if user types "ca" I show "擦拆礤嚓" Chinese characters list.

Is there something similar for Japanese?

I have found the table with Japanese transliteration: あa でde がga じji まm のno たta わwa 阿ae ... 芭bac 八bap 捌bat 覇bax 冊cek 測ces 策cez 癌aib. And I suggest to base on this information while implementing Japanese input. For example user need to type "bac" and device will show possible replacement option "芭".

Is there some common used input method that is based Latin symbols input?

Comment: Your examples are incorrect.  I've fixed the ones I know for sure (the others are definitely wrong though, as they don't make sense). Japanese has three distinct character sets in addition to occasionally using "Roman" characters (romaji).  Those are hiragana, katakana, and kanji.  Katakana and hiragana are completely phonetic and have easy conversions (though there are multiple schemes for "romanization" which people use).  Each Kanji (Chinese) character can have many pronunciations, and therefore many possible Latin (Roman) symbol equivalents.

Comment: I know the other transliterations are incorrect because all Japanese characters represent syllables that are either the n sound or syllables that end in a,i,u,e or o.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think that for hiragana, katakana I can use separate input modes with several symbols per each key that will be changed cyclic by repetitive pressing.
Do you know any of used schemes for romanization Kanji characters?

Comment: I used more than one when I was in Japan 25 years ago.  They were by no means simple.  Any decent scheme is context-sensitive, giving you ranked choices based not only in the frequency of the characters used, but also on what preceded it in the document and sometimes how frequently you used the words.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough system resources to implement very complicated schemes of Kanji romanization.
I just want to know if some scheme exists where each Kanji will be represent by some Latin symbols combination. And all that user should do to get Kanji is to type combination of Latin symbols and choose needed Kanji.

Comment: I suspect that such a scheme exists, but I'm not sure where you'd be able to find the necessary data. I hope that the "limited system resources" would allow for a table of a several megabytes, because even if you find the data it will surely be at least that big.  Best of luck to you!